# PHP equivalent of JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

PHP equivalent of this JavaScript regex (?<=(\s|^|,))(abc)(?=(\s|,|$)).

This regex is for the exact match of abc.

https://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/60

I tried but pattern error shows

Comment: Make sure to use delimeter `/ .. /` at both ends when using that regex in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `()` inside first and third group. `/(?<=\s|^|,)(abc)(?=\s|,|$)/` would work in both PHP and JS.

**[PHP](https://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/63)** and **[JS](https://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/64)** demo.

Comment: Thank you very much